# Is there a way to redirect to another route after res.json() in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a form where I want to output message when user is successfully registered and after that redirect them to another route.

So I have this piece of code in my post request to `/register`.

```
newUser.save()
  .then((user: any) => {
       res.json({ success })
       res.redirect('/')
   })
   .catch((error: string) => { throw error });
```

This send me success message which I can output in my React component but after that redirect doesn't fire.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or in this situation redirection should be in React component, for example?

Comment: You should redirect from the client, not server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. Once a response was sent, it cannot be changed.

Moreover, the response is obviously processed as XMLHttpRequest on client side. It wouldn't redirect a browser even if no JSON response was needed.

Client-side redirect should be performed after XHR response was received with `window.location`, or history API, or React router, in case it's used.